# What wireless USB adapter is supported out of the box by the most OSs?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, operating-systems, 802.11n

I always carry around a wireless USB adapter in my "toolkit." My current adapter is only 802.11g and has seen better days.  The male USB connecter us getting loose and Im afraid its one bad yank away from being broken.

So I was thinking of replacing it with an 802.11n model, but Im curious as to which model/chipset is supported out of the box by the most operating systems.  Naturally Windows needs to be supported, as well as Mac OS X, and as many Linux distros as possible.  BSD would be nice as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i've seen Ralink chipsets have pretty decent (official) driver support for linux, have official [OS X drivers](http://www.ralinktech.com/support.php?s=3) and [according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_wireless_drivers) is supported by the BSDs as well.

Luckily enough they're incredibly common and a good many wireless adaptors are built around them.

Answer (score 0):

Telewell Wireless B/G/N USB 2.0 v2 supports at least Windows and Linux straight from box. Ralink chipset inside.